# Photos with Audio Descriptions and Acid-Free labels for photos

Tags: photo, organization

I've got lots of photos from decades ago in my family.  I'm recording my aunts (in their 70's) as they talk about the photos. I ultimately plan to create some sort of web based app where photos will appear and viewers can listen to those my aunts talking about each photo.  There will also be ability for viewers to share their recollection on specific photos. Is there an app available that does this?

That's the high level question.  My immediate need is to locate acid-free stickers I can place on the back of the photos as I index them.  I do not want to put them in plastic bags.  Just simple labels that I can write a number on.  If I could find small, acid-free labels that are already numbered, that'd be better.

Comment: It would be better to split this into 2 questions as they're very different topics.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  I too encourage you to ask a new question for your second paragraph and to use the **edit** button to remove it from this one. You can use links to reference one question within another.  Also, every question, answer and comment you post here is already signed by your [user card](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/users/3949/marcus-graham) so there is no need to sign (or say thanks) within your questions.  The 2-minute [Tour] is well worth taking if you have not already.

Comment: Now that an answer has been posted to your first question, it should be the second one that is moved out into a new question.

Comment: Re: "acid-free" "adhesive labels" - simply google those search terms - a number of label suppliers, including Avery, have such a product. Pre-printed labels are also available. Check their catalogues to see if there is a combination.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any app that will do exactly what you want in your question about web display.

However, a photogallery will go a long way towards what you want to do.This could be a dedicated one such as [Coppermine](http://coppermine-gallery.net/) or [Gallery](http://galleryproject.org/) you will need to do some custom coding to add the audio facilities. Another alternative would be to use self-hosted Wordpress with its inbuilt gallery features, this would potentially need less custom coding as you could link the photo click event to the url of the audio file.

Be aware though that if you have a lot of photos their associated audio files are likely to be large and you may require a significant amount of storage.

This sounds like a very interesting project and I look forward to seeing how you get on with it.